# delay in starting Wildfly server

Tags: java, deployment, server, jboss, wildfly-8

Its a MAC system, macOS High Sierra V10.13.3, wildfly-8.0.0.Final
When I start the server, it takes nearly 30 minutes to start the server

When checked logs, most of the time is used for DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery) PeriodicRecovery related things. Is there any way I can avoid this? As I am using wildfly for some learning activities, these configurations can be avoided?

Comment: try re installing?

Comment: Is debug logging enabled?